# where are recursive list's for FTP described?

Tags: ftp, rfc

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_commands `LIST -R`, in the FTP protocol on servers that support it, return a recurisve directory listing. My question is...  where is this behavior defined? It's not in [RFC959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does not seem to be a standardised extension. A simple way to look for any related standards documents would be a `site:tools.ietf.org` query using your favourite search engine. https://www.ietf.org/mailman/listinfo/ftpext would be a good place to ask for additional pointers; that used to the be mailing list of the IETF WG defining FTP extensions.